# Broken Mathjax on Firefox

Tags: bug

This is on Firefox 37, no extensions and reproduced in Safe Mode. Ubuntu

[image]

I get 2 errors in the console:

```
TypeError: navigator.appVersion.match(...) is null
```

and

```
TypeError: this.queue is undefined
```

Comment: It's always good to include the mathjax here, so we can view it in a number of browsers. Or, at the very least, a link to the question.

Comment: [Link to the post in question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1226891) Working fine for me with FF 37.0.1 on OSX.

Comment: working fine with chrome  41.0 on OSX.

Comment: Works fine with 31.0 on OSX, too.

Comment: That post is just an example, the problem is global over all of math.stackexchange, and it affects other javascript code as well (the post preview for this post for example was not working)

Comment: Does MathJax work for you on other sites? Check [mathoverflow.se], [physics.se] and [stats.se] for MathJax errors.

Comment: Indeed, it fails with all of these sites. I dug up an official minimal sample http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-tex.html and the meaningful error is the `appVersion.match`... I reported it as an issue upstream: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to some flaky user-agent sniffing code in the MathJax project.

https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1155

hopefully it'll be fixed, so that it won't happen to anyone else. But in the meanwhile, changing the user-agent back to the default makes the javascript on math.stackexchange.com (and all other sites using Mathjax) work again.